# Slicing and copying a string in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, slice

I'm trying to slice a string and copy this new sliced part.

```
    char* makeWord(char *c, int j, int i){

    char *s;
    s = malloc(sizeof(char)*i-j)
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < i - j; k++){
        s[k] = c[j+k];
    }

    printf("%s ", s);

    return s;
}
```

I'm trying to return a pointer which copies the relevant part of the original string.

It is printing strange symbols in the end.

Example:

```
c[] = "hello darkness my old friend" 
makeWord(c, 0, 5); makeWord(c, 6,14); makeWord(c, 15, 17); makeWord(c, 18, 21);
```

> Generates:
>   hello  darknessmt_'3  myP  old  friendP

Thank you, sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: What do strings end with? Your `s` is missing something.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is redundant as it is always one

Comment: consider using more meaningful variable names than `i` and `j`

Comment: It's a good thing `sizeof(char)` is `1` too, because otherwise, `sizeof(char)*i-j` would be wrong; the multiply binds more tightly, so you'd calculate `sizeof(char)*i`, then subtract `j`, when you almost certainly want it the other way around. Yay for one error cancelling out others?

Answer (score 1):

A valid string in C requires a null-terminator.

You have to `malloc()` one additional byte to store it, and close your string with a `\0` after the last character.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you need to allocate a string buffer to hold `n` characters, you need `n+1` chars, the additional one for the terminating null character, `'\0'`. Also remember you have to set the terminator by yourself.
2. `sizeof(char)` is always 1 defined by the standard.

Try this:

```
char* makeWord(char *c, int start, int end) {

    char *s = malloc(end - start + 1);
    if (!s) return NULL;
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < end-start; k++){
        s[k] = c[start+k];
    }
    s[k] = '\0';

    printf("%s ", s);

    return s;
}
```